# Go 1.18 build error on Mac: "unix/syscall_darwin.1_13.go:25:3: //go:linkname must refer to declared function or variable"

Tags: macos, go

I upgraded to Go 1.18 on Mac 12+.

'go build' fails with errors like:

```
# golang.org/x/sys/unix
../../gopath/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20200116001909-b77594299b42/unix/syscall_darwin.1_13.go:25:3:
//go:linkname must refer to declared function or variable
../../gopath/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20200116001909-b77594299b42/unix/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.1_13.go:27:3:
//go:linkname must refer to declared function or variable
../../gopath/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20200116001909-b77594299b42/unix/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.1_13.go:40:3: 
//go:linkname must refer to declared function or variable
../../gopath/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20200116001909-b77594299b42/unix/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:28:3: 
//go:linkname must refer to declared function or variable
../../gopath/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20200116001909-b77594299b42/unix/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:43:3: 
//go:linkname must refer to declared function or variable
../../gopath/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20200116001909-b77594299b42/unix/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:59:3: 
//go:linkname must refer to declared function or variable
../../gopath/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20200116001909-b77594299b42/unix/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:75:3: 
//go:linkname must refer to declared function or variable
../../gopath/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20200116001909-b77594299b42/unix/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:90:3: 
//go:linkname must refer to declared function or variable
../../gopath/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20200116001909-b77594299b42/unix/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:105:3: 
//go:linkname must refer to declared function or variable
../../gopath/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20200116001909-b77594299b42/unix/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:121:3: 
//go:linkname must refer to declared function or variable
../../gopath/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20200116001909-b77594299b42/unix/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:121:3: 
too many errors

Compilation finished with exit code 2
```

Answer (score 347):

This was caused by an old version of `golang.org/x/sys` (mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/49219)). Fix is to update with:

```golang
go get -u golang.org/x/sys
```

Comment: i did run `go get -u golang.org/x/sys` but still, my build is failing with the above error :
/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20201112073958-5cba982894dd/unix/syscall_darwin.1_13.go:29:3: //go:linkname must refer to declared function or variable

Comment: is there a permanent solution to this? It seems I have to do this for every project I started

Comment: `'go get' is no longer supported outside a module.` Does anyone know an updated solution?

Comment: Ref `go get` no longer being supported outside a module - see [the release notes](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.18#go-get) "In GOPATH mode (with GO111MODULE=off), go get still builds and installs packages, as before.". So if you are not using modules set `GO111MODULE=off` (you would need to do this in order to build anyway).

Answer (score 7):

As [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys#section-readme) mentioned,

1. The easiest way : run `get -u golang.org/x/sys`.
2. Manual : git clone the repository to `$GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/sys`.

Answer (score 4):

I have faced same error and I fixed doing the following:

First I ran:

```bash
go get -u golang.org/x/sys
```

To update the `x/sys` library.

Then it printed some important information:

```
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20220704084225-05e143d24a9e
go: upgraded golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20200323222414-85ca7c5b95cd => v0.0.0-20220704084225-05e143d24a9e
```

With that in hands, I went to `go.mod` and I have placed the following line (before the `go 1.14` line):

```golang
replace golang.org/x/sys => golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20220704084225-05e143d24a9e
```

And finally I ran:

```bash
go mod vendor
```

Then it updated all the libraries:

```bash
go: downloading github.com/hashicorp/go-cleanhttp v0.5.1
go: downloading github.com/hashicorp/go-rootcerts v1.0.0
go: downloading github.com/mitchellh/colorstring v0.0.0-20190213212951-d06e56a500db
go: downloading github.com/mitchellh/cli v1.0.0
[...]
go: downloading github.com/golang/snappy v0.0.0-20180518054509-2e65f85255db
go: downloading github.com/agl/ed25519 v0.0.0-20170116200512-5312a6153412
go: downloading github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/to v0.4.0
```

Then it was fine

```
❯ go install .
❯ terraform --version
Terraform v0.13.5
```

EDIT:
Here I am using `modules`, if its not your case set `GO111MODULE=off`.

Answer (score 2):

If `go get -u golang.org/x/sys` doesn't work, make sure to remove such line in your `go.mod`:

```
replace golang.org/x/sys => golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20200826173525-f9321e4c35a6
```

Comment: go.mod does not have the line mentioned and go get command also does not resolve. What else can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope it will solve your problem as mine:

```
sudo go get golang.org/x/sys@latest
```