# Trouble with go get install for mcumgr

Tags: macos, go, installation

I am trying to install MCUMgr on MACos. Here is a link for mcumgr: https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/services/device_mgmt/mcumgr.html

I install the Go Programming Language and enter this command:

```
go install github.com/apache/mynewt-mcumgr-cli/mcumgr@latest
```

Upon doing this I get the following error:

```
go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20200223170610-d5e6a3e2c0ae/unix/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:28:3: //go:linkname must refer to declared function or variable
```

I then googled and found the following from stackoverflow: [Go 1.18 build error on Mac: "unix/syscall_darwin.1_13.go:25:3: //go:linkname must refer to declared function or variable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71507321/go-1-18-build-error-on-mac-unix-syscall-darwin-1-13-go253-golinkname-mus)

This gives me the following error:

```
go: golang.org/x/sys: unrecognized import path "golang.org/x": parse https://golang.org/x?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ()
```

I am stuck right now on how to install MCUMgr for MACos and wondering if someone has previously had the same issues?

Comment: Do you have a non-default GOPROXY set? Can you so `go get golang.org/x/sys@latest` instead?

Comment: @JimB I get the following error:
go: can't request version "latest" of the main module (golang.org/x/sys)

I have GOPROXY=""

Comment: @JimB I tried export GOPROXY=https://goproxy.io,direct.
Same error.

Comment: @Markus have you tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71508032/10718910?

Comment: @isavinof yes it is the one I linked in the post

Answer (score 0):

I used go 1.17 instead and used:

```
go get github.com/apache/mynewt-mcumgr-cli/mcumgr
```

Then into the bin folder where it is installed use `sudo ./mcumgr` to run.